# Websphere 7.X. JMX, how to enable all operations in JConsole?

Tags: java, websphere, jmx, websphere-7

When I open JConsole (using confugured .bat file), inside *AppManagement* Mbean node  I see many operations. But  most of them are disabled, enabled only one - "MoveModule" operation.. How to enable all JMX operations under *AppManagement* Mbean node (like "Install application", redeploy, uninstall  etc)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not possible. JConsole allows to invoke methods that only have parameters with simple types. That includes primitive types, wrapper classes for primitive types and strings. Methods that have parameters with other types cannot be invoked because JConsole doesn't know how to construct instances of these types.

Comment: Why not permit specifying null values for them instead?